# What are the factors on the volume of a drop?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Earlier today I grabbed a flask of sweetener and reading through the nutrition info I found this "Approximately 0.2cal per 0.2mL or drop". So I started thinking, what affects the volume of a drop? Is it altered on the surface it is dripping from, the viscosity or the density of the liquid itself, by the gas/mean it is immersed into?

What are the most important factors that alter the drop-volume relation?

Comment: FYI,they're referring to a non-ISO standard unit of measure called a "drop."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_(unit) . The general drop size certainly depends on viscosity and aperture.  Check out the famous pitch-drop experiments.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft after a little reasearch I found out that it was a standard, I just like to give some background to questions when I can. Didn't know it was non-ISO though, hate non-ISO.

Comment: Possibly relevant answer to earlier question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/143603/26969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of drops of a Newtonian liquid ejected from an aperture in a laminar regime without simultaneous air intake at that aperture are governed by two non-dimensional numbers, that combine the inertial forces, viscous forces and capillary forces (which have different dependences on the length scale, i.e. size of aperture). There are several ways to combine them, but usual choices are the Reynolds and Ohnesorge numbers.

The geometry of the outlet can also change things, though, since it will affect the velocity profile. At small scales or large speeds the air flow can also be important. So on the whole there's very little universality in drop size! You should be able to obtain quite different ones with the same liquid if you can attain different speeds of ejection, or if you change the way you produce them.

This complexity makes it difficult to point an article in particular as we have rather a negative result here: no universality. You can check Jens Eggers' 2005 review in ZAMP, many of his other papers on drops can give you examples of drop formation: http://www2.maths.bris.ac.uk/~majge/

Comment: links? pls?   examples?

Comment: This answer works mostly for "fast" flow. For applications like sweeteners etc, where you attempt to use a dropper for dosing, I believe the key parameters are the surface tension and the aperture of the dropper. Might be worth adding those relationships to your answer.

Comment: This does not make a dimensionless number. For very slow detachment you will have the capillary number which compares viscous and surface tension effects, and possibly a gravity-related number. The case of slow dripping may be even more complex to understand if there is some wetting of the external surface of the dropper.