# Adding a tracer to the surface of a water droplet

Tags: fluid-dynamics, particle-physics, experimental-physics

I have a 2 mm water droplet generated by a syringe and falling down. I am using two perpendicular cameras to capture simultaneous frames from it. I need to track the droplet during the time and reconstruct it (through consecutive frames). However, only the border of the droplet (which is an ellipse) is distinguishable in each frame and I do not have any traceable point **on the surface** of the droplet to use it as a tracer (each point on the droplet surface will give me a point **inside** the corresponding ellipse on each frame). I want to add one or few **very small particles/tracers** in the order of my pixel dimension (e.g. 0.05 mm or even less which are still detectable through my cameras) such that while the droplet wobbling or revolving during falling down, always **remain on the surface** of the droplet and don't go inside it. Which material or **technique** do you think is more appropriate for this purpose?

Please let me know if you know any reference or paper used your suggestion.
for more information please see [this Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142504/) as well.

[image]

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, you wish to go for a tracer particle technique instead of the mirror technique that @Floris suggested in answer to [your previous question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142504). Could you explain your rational? It seems to me that you want your measurement technique to be as non-intrusive as possible, while adding particles certainly doesn't classify as non-intrusive. Moreover, adding particles is probably not even easier to do. Bottom line: I don't see benefits of this method over the mirrors, could you elaborate on your view?

Comment: Infact, I asked this question the day before @Floris posted his nice answer for using mirrors. I decided to use one camera for YZ plane and another camera for both XY and XZ planes (I will put the 2nd camera on XY (front) plane, however through using mirrors it will be able to see the XZ (top) view as well). If I use two opposite mirrors in 45 degree to bring XZ view in front of camera which is on XY plane, the picture is not invert but I should **calibrate** the picture that the 2nd mirror gives to the camera (e.g. with another object in the mirror which has a known real length). Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some problems with Teflon particles. Prior to droplet separation from the syringe, the Teflon particle can roll down along the surface of the droplet, so you'll only have your tracer at the bottom of the droplet. This movement of the particle along the surface will not take place when the droplet is in free fall. This movement will be less important for small particles, but it is more difficult to register a very small particle by a camera. So you may wish to consider using phosphorescent particles (http://www.cospheric.com/PHYGPMS_phosphorescent_yellowgreen_microspheres.htm ; see their note on the surfactant).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please describe: 1- Why  movement of the particle along the surface will not take place when the droplet is in free fall? 2- How can I make sure that phosphorescent particles don't roll down to the bottom of droplet? 3- What will cause this particle(s) to remain always on the surface (not to travel into the droplet) and while $\rho=1.1$ $g/cc$, not to go down the droplet surface?

Comment: @Hossein: 1. Because gravity does not cause relative motion of the droplet and the particle in weightlessness of free fall. 2. By using smaller particles (see below). 3. They will remain on the surface if covered by a surfactant making them hydrophobic - due to surface tension (you know that some insects walk on water). They will not go down along the droplet surface (or will go down slowly) if they are small enough, so volume effects, such as gravity, will be less important than surface effects, such as air drag (you know that aerosols fall slowly in air).

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using water with a dye like a deep blue to be nearly opaque. Illuminate with an array of LEDs. Each bright spot reflected from the droplet is an LED. You can add a few strategic red LEDs among all white as reference.

Working out the most convenient geometry will tell if you need the LEDs on some curved surface in space or if a flat panel will do. I think you can get pretty good data this way and quite high resolution as far as number of points on the drop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I have some questions: 1- How much would be the diameter of LED spot on droplet (diameter of LED beam)? 2- How do we make sure that the light doesn't go through the droplet to refract inside it and will be reflected from the surface? 3- Would you please describe the first sentence of 2nd paragraph? Thanks again

Comment: The size of the spot will depend on the size of the led and its distance and the radius of curvature of the drop. The drop will act like a convex mirror and the light spot will be vary small. Avoid diffraction by using a dye so the drop is not transparent and any light through the surface is absorbed. You can use a hemisphere with hundreds of LEDs as the source. If you use a green one in the center and some red ones to define axis and the rest white, you could have hundreds of points on the surface of the drop and a coordinate system that they map to. Or a hemisphere with holes and a flash.

Comment: Thanks again. If you read the "complementary descriptions" [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142504/finding-equation-of-a-water-droplet) you will find that what is interesting for me in the above answer! However, I would like to know your opinion regarding adding "phosphorescent particles" (the 2nd answer below). Since I must select ONLY one method, which one do you think that is more applicable and accurate for marking a droplet in this case? ...please read the next comment

Comment: by accuracy, I mean any kind of error that may happen in marking process through each method; e.g. marker goes (even a bit) inside the droplet that I don't want OR led light is not narrow enough to give me the desired measurement accuracy in the order of one pixel dimension in my frames which is 50$\mu$ and any other issue related to accuracy of method during implementation. Thanks

Comment: Convex mirrors produce upright images that are reduced in size and behind the mirror (distance is a negative number).  Say 1mm surface mount LEDs are 500mm from the drop and form a grid with an LED every 20mm. Radius of the drop is 2mm. Focal length of the mirror is 1mm. Use the mirror equation an find magnification. I better draw a diagram for myself to get image size. But, with the position of the two cameras and the LEDs you should be able to map the shape of the droplet with as many points as you need.